# VS 2010 with MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

> > I have vs 2010 Express but I can't find MVC 4 projects type on it ! any help please to add this feature or something ?

Answer (score 1):

> I have vs 2010 Express but I can't find MVC 4 projects type on it !

That's normal. ASP.NET MVC 4 comes with VS 2012. You could install it separately though from [`this link`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683) if you want to use it with VS 2010.

Comment: you mean to install vs 2012 ?

Comment: No, I mean to install ASP.NET MVC 4 from the link I provided in my answer. But why not just upgrade to VS 2012? Soon there will be VS 2013 out, so why still use VS 2010?

Comment: I will ... it is just my first try with MVC !

Comment: and should I install .net 4.5 ??

Comment: No, that's not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You should install visual studio 2010 Ultimate.

Comment: seems I will install vs 2012 instead if I was supposed to install something

Comment: @Paul: VS 2010 ultimate doesn't ship with ASP.NET MVC 4.

Answer (score 0):

> MVC4 comes with Visual Studio 2012. For updates and to use Web API, SignalR, Facebook Applications, etc., you need to install the ASP.NET Fall 2012 Update, presented by Scott Hanselman.Here is a link [ASP.NET Fall 2012 Update Release Candidate](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETAndWebTools20122ReleaseCandidate.aspx).